# Libevent. Configuring event_base with thread support

Tags: c++, c, libevent

According to libevent [documentation](http://www.wangafu.net/~nickm/libevent-2.1/doxygen/html/thread_8h.html#ac0c39231d48295aff378fd9f65b2569a) there's a function to make `event_base` structure thread safe:

```
EVENT2_EXPORT_SYMBOL int evthread_make_base_notifiabe(struct event_base* base)
```

Documentation also states that: "*You shouldn't need to call this by hand; configuring the base with thread support should be necessary and sufficient.*"

There's:

```
EVENT2_EXPORT_SYMBOL struct event_base* event_base_new_with_config(const struct event_config *) 
EVENT2_EXPORT_SYMBOL int event_config_set_flag (struct event_config *cfg, int flag)
```

But I can't just figure out how to configure event_base to get the same effect as with `evthread_make_base_notifiable`. Any ideas?

Comment: I think the documentation is probably wrong, and libevent2 is simply not thread-safe. In order to use it with threads, you need to call an init function to tell it which locking callbacks to use. But if libevent2 is used by multiple libraries in the same program, there is no safe way to ensure that this takes place before another one uses the libevent2 interfaces. This is a very common design bug.

Comment: Some functions actually are thread safe. There are functions `evthread_use_pthreads` and `evthread_use_windows_threads` to choose between thread APIs.

Comment: A library is not thread-safe if you have to call an initialization function which isn't itself synchronized before you can use it. This is because multiple libraries being used in your program might each use the library and not be aware of one another, and both call the init function such that the calls race with one another. As I said before, this is a *classic* design flaw.

Comment: But that does not mean that once initialized, some of those functions cannot bet thread safe. And that's what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Libevent book](http://www.wangafu.net/~nickm/libevent-book/Ref1_libsetup.html), you have to tell Libevent which locking functions to use. You do this by invoking either `evthread_use_windows_threads()` or `evthread_use_pthreads()` depending on your platform. You need to do this before you call any Libevent function that allocates a structure that needs to be shared between threads. You'll also need to add something like `-levent_thread` to your linker flags.

Comment: Please tell me where to enter - "-levent_thread" ?

Answer (score 0):

If you create the event base like this:

```
struct event_config* config = event_config_new();

if ((m_base = event_base_new_with_config(config)) == NULL)
{
    cout << "Failed to create an event base";
}

event_config_free(config);
```

Then the event base will be thread safe (at least the event_add and event_base_once functions which are enough to remove the thread-safety issue by creating an event with the task and run it on the right thread).

In http://www.wangafu.net/~nickm/libevent-book/Ref2_eventbase.html is written that you can configure the no lock flag (EVENT_BASE_FLAG_NOLOCK) so by default it is locked.
All this may not be relevant to very old versions of libevent where locking mechanism hasn't yet introduced.